# Error while submitting ipa onto AppStore

Tags: ios, eclipse, libgdx, ipa, robovm

I'm working on a libgdx project and using robovm to try and deploy my project on iOS. I've build an ipa using the robovm tool in eclipse.

While submitting the ipa using Application Loader, I get the below error:

> **Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires launch story board in bundle BundleNameHere**
>
> **Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,
>   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown...etc**

On doing some research I understand these can be done away with by checking an option in **Xcode** for Requires Full Screen. However, I am unsure how to handle this in libgdx.

I am assuming that I need to do some additional settings in my **libgdx/robovm** project that I've missed.

Can anyone point out the required settings, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using RoboVM you need to edit the info.plist.xml file. As per Bunty Madan's answer you need to set:

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
```

If this does not work, please supply your full info.plist.xml file (just redact any personal ID's if you use any)

Comment: Works perfectly. Ty all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to specify how your `iOS` app is supposed to handle multitasking on `iPad`.
For now if your app is not going to support the multitasking feature just check `requireFullScreen` option in project setting.

else for making direct entry into `plist`here is the ket for that.

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key><true/>
```

And also please validate your `LaunchImage` storyboard or image whatever you using.

Try this, hope it will help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By my experience this issue already . Did you uncheck the unnecessary orientations in plist for iPAD`, UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`

[image]